# AWS Firehose transform Lambda function throws Lambda.MissingRecordId error for every record

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I'm using AWS firehose with an S3 backup and an S3 destination bucket, and it works great. The problem arises when I try to transform the data with a Lambda function.

I'm using the .NET AWS SDK, my Lambda function is written in C# and is using the included firehose transform example:

```
[assembly:LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.JsonSerializer))]

namespace LambdaFunctions
{
    public class Function
    {
        public KinesisFirehoseResponse FunctionHandler(KinesisFirehoseEvent evnt, ILambdaContext context)
        {
            context.Logger.LogLine($"InvocationId: {evnt.InvocationId}");
            context.Logger.LogLine($"DeliveryStreamArn: {evnt.DeliveryStreamArn}");
            context.Logger.LogLine($"Region: {evnt.Region}");

            KinesisFirehoseResponse response = new KinesisFirehoseResponse
            {
                Records = new List<KinesisFirehoseResponse.FirehoseRecord>()
            };

            foreach (KinesisFirehoseEvent.FirehoseRecord record in evnt.Records)
            {
                context.Logger.LogLine($"\tRecordId: {record.RecordId}");
                context.Logger.LogLine($"\t\tApproximateArrivalEpoch: {record.ApproximateArrivalEpoch}");
                context.Logger.LogLine($"\t\tApproximateArrivalTimestamp: {record.ApproximateArrivalTimestamp}");
                context.Logger.LogLine($"\t\tData: {record.DecodeData()}");

                // Transform data: For example ToUpper the data
                KinesisFirehoseResponse.FirehoseRecord transformedRecord = new KinesisFirehoseResponse.FirehoseRecord
                {
                    RecordId = record.RecordId,
                    Result = KinesisFirehoseResponse.TRANSFORMED_STATE_OK
                };

                transformedRecord.EncodeData(record.DecodeData().ToUpperInvariant());

                response.Records.Add(transformedRecord);
            }

            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

The data is successfully & correctly processed by the transform Lambda function (as indicated by tests & logs).

However, the data is not successfully returned by the Lambda function to the S3 destination bucket, all of the records are unsuccessfully processed.

This error is returned for each record:

```
{
    "attemptsMade": 1,
    "arrivalTimestamp": 1590656820209,
    "errorCode": "Lambda.MissingRecordId",
    "errorMessage": "One or more record Ids were not returned. Ensure that the Lambda function returns all received record Ids.",
    "attemptEndingTimestamp": 1590656883464,
    "rawData": "dGVzdDE=",
    "lambdaArn": "arn:aws:lambda:Region:AccountNumber:function:transform-function:$LATEST"
}
```

I'm at a loss as to why or where this error is occurring. I know the Lambda function is returning the correct response, recordId included.

I've recreated all the resources, applied and re-applied permissions, done just about everything I can think of.

This issue doesn't happen when using the Node.js or Python versions, it seems to be unique to the .NET implementation.

**EDIT:**

I forgot to add the serializer assembly attribute to the original code block which ended up being the source of the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C# example provided by AWS is out of date, specifically this serialization package:

```
Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson
```

To solve this issue, simply replace the package with this one:

```
Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json
```

and update the assembly attribute like so:

```
[assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer))]

namespace LambdaFunctions
{
    ...
```

This serialization package is mentioned in the AWS Documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/csharp-handler.html), under "Serializing Lambda functions".

However, Amazon have not yet updated the SDK examples to reflect this change (or at least, this example specifically), causing the function to fail when deployed.